# Marker.getTag() returns null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In my code i have two activity first activity show makers on map and second activity shows information about that marker.In async task i am searching some location and adding information object as tag to maker. Just as we do

```
maker.setTag(obj);
```

when i click on marker onMarkerclick() is called and i get obj by invoking getTag() on marker and second activity starts and show details

Till here all thing works fine. But when i press back button and click that marker again it return null from marker.getTag(). Below is my onMarkerClick method

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    if (marker.getTag().toString().equals("JobSeeker")) {
   // this is user current location show i dont want to do anything when marker is clicked
        return false;
    }



    if (previousMarker != null && previousMarker.equals(marker)) {
   //this code is executed if marker is clicked second time

        LinkedTreeMap jobPost = (LinkedTreeMap) marker.getTag();
        marker.setTag(jobPost);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, JobSearchResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("JobPost", jobPost);

        Toast.makeText(this, "jobPostdetails" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
    // just showing some toast that marker is selected
        previousMarker = marker;
        Toast.makeText(this, "selected" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        marker.showInfoWindow();

    }

    return false;
}
```

Please help me. I don't know where i am worng or it might be some silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reload markers data. For example

```
map.clear();
...
List<CustomModel> models = getModels();
foreach( CustomModels m : models ){
  Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(
  new MarkerOptions()
      .position(m.getLocation())
      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img_userpin)));
 marker.setTag(m);
}
```